# How long did it take to program Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, development

How long did it take the Stack Overflow developers to build the Stack Overflow site (in the state where you could ask questions and get answers, vote, and post comments)?

Comment: @Wolf it can take years or months to program any web site.

Comment: ok @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1194651576914370560

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably [6-8 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/369802), if you check [this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/):

> I'm in no way trying to conflate this with the meaning of my last blog post, but after a six month gestation, we just gave birth to a public website.

Comment: I'm surprised it wasn't 6-8 weeks

Comment: @hjpotter92 [Steve](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Six-Weeks-Steve) wasn't involved.

Comment: @hjpotter92: That was said in the *middle* of the process, [published 2008-05-18](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) (about 14 weeks before the actual launch). When did the public beta start?